# Why would the Emperor send his personal troops to help the Harkonnen?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

I have just seen the new Dune movie (2021) and I really liked it, but I do not understand the Emperor's actions completely. Note that I have not read any of the books, and I still wish to more-or-less blindly experience the second part of the movie (hoping it gets made) so if the answer hinges on crucial plot points or striking revelations from the second half of the book, I would appreciate a disclaimer before you get to it :-)

The Emperor (I am told he is named Shaddam) is getting the mighty houses Harkonnen and Atreides to go to war and exhaust their resources so he can stay on top himself. To do that he grants Atreides stewardship of Arrakis, and then supports Harkonnen to take it back in a massive planetary invasion, ending the Atreides and rendering the Harkonnen in financial trouble. To support that invasion, he lends the Harkonnen his elite throat-singing soldiers, the Sardaukar.

But as the invasion occurs, on several instances people recognise Sardaukar and understand that the Emperor has violated his neutrality. This is a big deal and enough for Paul to start discussing a "holy war" against the imperial authority, which he implies many houses would join particularly because the Emperor is no longer impartial.

So sending Sardaukar seems like a great misstep on the part of Shaddam. Why did he do that? I understand that in the book these soldiers are disguised as Harkonnen, but I'm sure that they are still recognised. Why would Shaddam not support the Harkonnen in a way that cannot be traced back to him as clearly? E.g., buy them generic mercenaries, or just provide financial means?

Comment: *"The Atreides are building a secret army," the Emperor said. "And the
Duke is becoming too popular with the other Great Houses of the Empire ... He could be a threat to me. I have ordered Duke Atreides to go to the planet Dune ... His people will take over and mine the spice, replacing their enemies the Harkonnens. The Atreides think this is a victory for them.*

Comment: *They think it will give them great power. But once they are on Dune, Baron Harkonnen will return and make a sneak attack on them. He will get rid of the Atreides for me. I have promised him five legions of my Sardaukar terror troops"* - [Dune (1984) Storybook](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1152706.Dune_Storybook).

Comment: @Machavity your assertion that the movie tag is for story identification only contradicts the tag description.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Fair enough, but your question is not specifically about the movie (it might have inspired the question, but it's about Dune in general)

Comment: @Machavity Also fair, though I don't really know if the reason for my question was the movie making a change to the story, or them just leaving stuff out. In any case I'll keep a watch on it until the [meta debate](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13505/how-should-we-tag-the-dune-movies?cb=1) concludes and then tag it appropriately.

Comment: Re: "I still wish to more-or-less blindly experience the **second part** of the movie" -- and the third part, and the fourth.

Comment: Btw: "Warner Bros. and Legendary Pictures officially greenlit Dune: Part Two on October 26, 2021, with a scheduled release date of October 20, 2023"

Comment: "*[...] people recognise Sardaukar and understand that the Emperor has violated his neutrality. This is a big deal and enough for Paul to start discussing a "holy war" against the imperial authority, which he implies many houses would join particularly because the Emperor is no longer impartial.*" If you have only seen the first movie, then where are you getting this information from? It is not mentioned at all in Dune (2021). All we can discern from the movie that just premiered is that the Sardaukar appear to be for hire... to those who can afford it.

Comment: @TylerH in my recollection, the plot point of "Sardaukar present = emperor is involved = emperor is not neutral" was mentioned it at least twice, the latter time to Kynes right before she went and got herself killed.

Comment: @KeizerHarm It's mentioned that Sardaukar are the Emperor's personal assassin army, and that that means the Emperor is involved, but there's not really any discussion about the Emperor being famously neutral or anything. And there's certainly nothing from Paul (or anyone else) about a "holy war" (my understanding is that heavily involves the Fremen and will take place in Part 2 or 3 movies, whenever they end up being released).

Comment: @TylerH did we watch the same movie? Paul has an extended vision about a holy war in his name during the scene in the tent and after recovering, proposes an alternative (marrying the emperor's daughter, becoming emperor himself). Again the only reason he mentions it is he believes that people would start a fight with the emperor and he can offer him an alternative.

Comment: @KeizerHarm I watched the 2021 movie with Timothee Chalamet on HBO Now. From what I recall he had a vision about a war in his name, fighting with the Fremen, and chasing after whoever Zendaya's character is, but nothing about it being a *holy* war or ever mentioning the emperor or his daughter. Maybe they showed a different cut in theaters? If so that's going to really upset me.

Comment: @TylerH I wish I could give you a timestamp but I don't have HBO Max, all I have is my recollection of the movie. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @KeizerHarm No worries; I'll have to go back and watch that part again... but I strongly suspect a fair bit of this information is coming from non-2021-movie sources (which is not surprising given how many such sources exist!) :-)

Comment: It's important to note too that in the book, the Sardaukar were disguised in Harkonnen uniforms, not the iconic Sardaukar uniforms. I'd say it was done this way so that we (the audience) get that it's Sardaukar straight way. I personally preferred that it was true to the book.

Comment: "It seems the Emperor has chosen a side" - Jessica

Comment: @Möoz Did you notice how far backwards that was?

Of course it's important to note that in the book, the Sardaukar were disguised in Harkonnen uniforms. (What did you think "iconic" added?) 

How could you imagine, let alone say, that was done so the audience got it was Sardaukar straightaway? (Taking "straight way" as a lazy typo that should have been "straightaway". Was it?)

Wasn't the one and only point that no-one should ever "get" Sardaukar were involved?

What did I miss?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are schemes within schemes going on here. The Emperor fears Duke Leto and his heirs as possible contenders to the Corrino throne, the Harkonnen want their ancient enemy (the Atreides) dead and the Spacing Guild see a vergence in the Force centred around a boy.

The Emperor and the Baron hatch a plan together. The Emperor will order the Harkonnen off the planet, allegedly in disgrace for failing to harvest enough Spice. Leto will be ordered to take over the planet, leaving him open for a counter-attack. The Guild will offer passage to the planet (for a fat fee paid in spice) and in return for attacking the Atreides, the Emperor will give the Harkonnen permanent control of Arrakis as well as an  indefinite seat on the CHOAM board and various other considerations.

Note that on their own, the Harkonnen don't have enough troops to destroy the Duke's troops (or they would have invaded Caladan years ago), but supplemented with hidden Sardaukar, there'll be enough of an advantage to kill the Duke's men and capture him and his family.

> “The main point,” Piter said, “is this: since House Harkonnen is being
> used to do the Imperial dirty work, we’ve gained a true advantage.
> It’s a dangerous advantage, to be sure, but if used cautiously, will
> bring House Harkonnen greater wealth than that of any other House in
> the Imperium.”
>
> “You have no idea how much wealth is involved, Feyd,” the Baron said. “Not in your wildest imaginings. To begin, we’ll have an irrevocable directorship in the CHOAM Company.”
>
> <sub><sup>Dune</sup></sub>

In the novel Leto was expecting a *small* number of Sardaukar to be used against them and was hoping to counter them with a force of Fremen soldiers. He could then show the captives to the Landsraat to further weaken Shaddam's position and cement his own.

> “Four or five battalions all told, Sire. No more. Guild
> troop-transport costs being what they are.”
>
> “Then five battalions of Fremen plus our own forces ought to do it.
> Let us have a few captive Sardaukar to parade in front of the
> Landsraad Council and matters will be much different–profits or no
> profits.”

What he didn't count on was that the Harkonnen would be willing to bear the cost of bringing quite so many troops to Arrakis and that the Emperor would commit so many of his own crack troops to their destruction. The Emperor, on the other hand seems to feel that if he's in for a penny, he's in for a pound, especially if he's not paying the transport costs.

> “Expensive,” the Baron sneered. “The damnable Guild monopoly on space would’ve ruined us if I hadn’t planned for this expense long ago. You should know, Rabban, that we bore the entire brunt of it. We even paid for transport of the Sardaukar.”

Comment: So in the novel Leto was expecting the attack, including imperial support? That's quite a departure from was seen on the screen!

Comment: Small correction: the Harkonnens COULD have enough force to defeat Atreides on Caladan. But transporting troops by the Guild is prohibitively expensive. IIRC Harkonnens could afford to send to Caladan few brigades at most, before going completely, totally and instantly broke. Remember that Hawat was estimating total of 10 brigades or so (IIRC) as a maximum of what Harkonnens could afford. He made a mistake, but I believe that without Sardaukar, Atreides could hold out against full force of Harkonnens. Depending on factors, of course.

Comment: @KeizerHarm - Movie has to make shortcuts somewhere. Good place as any. But yes, Leto knew there will be Sardaukar in Harkonnen livery in the attack. He literally says so in the book: *“Disguised in Harkonnen livery, no doubt,” the Duke said. “But the soldier
fanatics nonetheless.”*

Comment: @AcePL - I don't think there's any indication that the Harkonnen forces would outmatch the Atreides on a level playing field. If anything you'd expect them to be quite evenly matched

Comment: Yes and no. Harkonnens gained in significance when gained CHOAM directorship. After that they could pay to recruit, train and equip much larger force than if supported from 1 planet's resources. And that directorship came to Baron Vladimir, maybe one gen prior. Atreides forces were superior in training to most, if not all except Sardaukar, true, but *nec Hercules contra plures...*. Especially if defense is planned for the reasonably estimated attack force, which is constricted by Guild fare prices. I don't think that even if Hawat knew H had 8 legions, he would plan for all of them attacking.

Comment: @AcePL - Don't forget that the Baron's fighting forces were depleted by generations of dire performance on Arrakis.

Comment: ... and yet he had 8 legions to attack with on Arrakis. True, he lost 6 of them there during attack or in the two years following, but it couldn't be so bad if their loss/kill ratio was much better than Sardaukar (2:1 vs 5:1). Unless those garritroops were oppressing other than Fremen and Sardaukar fought none other than Fremen (which we know isn't true).

Comment: Worth mentioning the line from the book that mentions Gurney, Duncan and Thufir had trained a small force of men to be as good as Sardaukar. That was another motive for the emperor to try to remove the Atreides in a non-quite-head-on confrontation, and before they could train more.

Comment: @Acepl I doubt the baron could have succeeded in invading Caladan. Too well prepared for defense. Leto had air and sea power and considered that the decisive advantage. He was the better strategist.

Comment: @StianYttervik - All valid points. But I have a uneasy feeling you didn't read carefully all my comments. The one where defense is prepared for reasonable scale of attack, which in turn is decided by treasure one's willing to spend is most relevant. Somehow Hawat was not prepared for attack on Arrakis which EVERYONE KNEW IS COMING. It is possible Harkonnen knew the quality of his forces and didn't want to attack on Caladan, of course, But still, to send 10 legions to Caladan or to Arrakis...  Logistically same problem and 10 legions would be beyond anything defenders expected.

Comment: Also remembering that shields aren't used on Arrakis, so defences are much weaker than they'd be on any other world.

Comment: @Seperatrix - They're extensively used in the city

Comment: Just to mention, I don’t think there was a “reduction in rates” by the guild. In the books I seem to remember the Baron stating “if you exploit this world for spice for the following 50 years it will not begin to cover the expenses we’ve had”. This is also while he explains the Harkonen have paid the full transport including Sardaukars.

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba - Worthy of its own question, perhaps? I'm sure there was mention of the Guild offering cut price transit

Comment: I’ve reviewed my copy of Dune (in Spanish though) and it seems to indicate the Harkonen supportted the FULL cost. The Barom even quotes “Risk Tariff” (in Spanish at least)

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba - You are indeed correct. I've tracked down the quote about "*Hazard rates*".

Comment: For the record, the guild reducing transport fares happens later, when Paul drinks the Water of Life and sees the ships of the Guild around Arrakis. He explains to his mother and Chani that "The Guild itself caused this by spreading tales about what we do here and by reducing troop transport fares to a point where even the poorest Houses are up there now waiting to loot us."

Comment: +1 for the "vergence in the force around the boy", made me chuckle:)

Answer (score 20):

### The Atreides were a threat to Imperial power

Duke Leto was popular in the Landstraad, the council of noble houses that acted as a counterbalance to Imperial power.

In addition, he had built a cadre of troops who were *almost* as good as Sardaukar and, if left on Caladan, would undoubtedly train more. It’s possible they were *better*, Sardaukar training had declined under Shaddam’s rule. The entire reason that all 81 Emporers were Corinos was because of the mythic fighting quality of the Sadaukar. Mythic is used deliberately - yes, elite fighting units are elite due to training, leadership and equipment but the mythos is *also* important: knowing you are fighting Royal Marine Commandos, or US Navy Seals , or French Foreign Legionnaires, or Australian SAS is not good for your morale.

From the Emporer’s point of view Leto and the Atreides had to go.

### It didn’t matter what people *knew*, it mattered what they could *prove*

Leto underestimated how much Baron Harkonnen wanted him dead and his line destroyed. He expected raids possibly with Sardaukar involved and he saw this as an opportunity to expose the Emperor. He thought that he would be in a fight he could (possibly) win. He didn’t know that the Baron was prepared to virtually bankrupt his House to bring overwhelming force to bear. The Emperor did.

Many people would be able to report the presence of Sadaukar but no one on the Atreides side would be able to prove it.

This is a positive benefit to the Emperor, not only has he disposed of a powerful and dangerous rival, he has shown all the other Houses Major that he can do so with impunity. Everyone would know he broke the rules, but no one would be able to do anything about it for fear that disguised and plausibly deniable Sadaukar would be on their doorstep next. One of the most important targets for this “lesson” was Baron Harkonnen himself. It was not lost on the Baron that the Emperor was a dangerous ally.

Comment: 2021 film Nitpick: Sardaukar are not disguised

Answer (score 19):

The Harkonnen are not mere puppets for the Emperor to order about as he pleases. They need an incentive to be part of his trap, assurance that he won't just betray them in turn.

It's precisely because the risk of committing Sardaukar is so great, that the Harkonnen demand them. It assures them that the Emperor is serious, and not just playing games.

They're also a nearly unparalleled fighting force, much better than mercenaries.

Answer (score 15):

I'll address one side of the question: not why the Emperor sent the Sardaukar, but simply how he planned on getting away with it.

This is an excerpt from the book, when Baron Harkonnen gives instructions to Rabban after reconquering Arrakis:

> “M’Lord….” Rabban hesitated, frowning. “I’ve always felt that we
> underestimated the Fremen, both in numbers and in—”
> “Ignore them, boy! They’re rabble. It’s the populous towns, cities, and
> villages that concern us. A great many people there, eh?”
> “A great many, m’Lord.”
> “They worry me, Rabban.”
> “Worry you?”
> “Oh… ninety per cent of them are of no concern. **But there are always a
> few… Houses Minor and so on, people of ambition who might try a dangerous
> thing. If one of them should get off Arrakis with an unpleasant story about what happened here, I’d be most displeased.** Have you any idea how displeased I’d be?”
> Rabban swallowed.
> “**You must take immediate measures to hold a hostage from each House
> Minor,” the Baron said. “As far as anyone off Arrakis must learn, this was
> straightforward House-to-House battle. The Sardaukar had no part in it, you
> understand?** The Duke was offered the usual quarter and exile, but he died in an
> unfortunate accident before he could accept. He was about to accept, though.
> That is the story. **And any rumor that there were Sardaukar here, it must be
> laughed at.**”
> “As the Emperor wishes it,” Rabban said.
> “As the Emperor wishes it.”
> “What about the smugglers?”
> **“No one believes smugglers, Rabban. They are tolerated, but not believed.
> At any rate, you’ll be spreading some bribes in that quarter… and taking other
> measures which I’m sure you can think of.”**
> “Yes, m’Lord.”

So the Emperor and the Baron know they can't really hide the whole matter, there are simply too many witnesses. Instead they take countermeasures, by taking hostages, spreading lies, and bribing. Some people will know it, but no one will dare to speak. Especially because the Houses Minor are too weak without the Atreides.

Answer (score 5):

The Emperor believes that House Atreides represents a political threat and wants the Atreides destroyed before they gain too much support, so he entices the Harkonnens to attack their favourite enemy and sweetens the deal by promising a guaranteed victory with his support.
It doesn't take much effort since the Atreides and Harkonnen have been mortal enemies for the past 10,000 years.

With that in mind, the Sardaukar's role in the Harkonnen's assault on the Atreides holdings on Arrakis is to ensure the job is done quickly and thoroughly, and as a lever to get the Baron Harkonnen to agree to do it.

In the book and previous adaptations, the Sardaukar explicitly wore Harkonnen uniforms for deniability, but if you leave no survivors, you don't need to be deniable...

From the Emperor's point of view, it's a safe bet.

- House Harkonnen aren't going to bite the hand that feeds them.
- House Atreides will be destroyed and in no position to comment if they even figure out what's going on.
- The Smugglers on Arrakis are irrelevant
- The Fremen aren't even in his head

And nobody else is going to be in a position to see or say anything to anyone who can do anything about it.

Nobody considered that the Heir to House Atreides would survive, learn the truth, join the Fremen and.. Do the things that will be revealed in Part 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

This is another case of Hollywood dumbing down. In the book, the Sardukar take great pains to **not** be identified, by all being dressed in Harkonnen uniforms and taking every other possible precaution.

As to why hatch the whole scheme in the first place: Herbert cribbed the political system of the Empire(broadly speaking) from that of the historical Holy Roman Empire(e.g. the Landsrad, position of powerful guilds, etc), with a far-from all powerful Emperor and the Great Houses standing in for the Prince Electors(in power roughly, obviously in Dune the Emperor isn't elected) and the minor houses for the myriad smaller players in the HRE. So having the Emperor discretely help one of them to take out his main potential rival, leaving the former indebted to him, while publicly keeping his hands clean is rather mundane actually.

Answer (score -5):

There was never a good reason either for throwing the Harkonnens off Dune, or for giving Dune to the Atreides, as such.

It was never properly stated, but the reader might be supposed to discern that the Emperor - for no clear reason - feared the Atreides.

More clearly, Shaddam was happy to use Harkonnen to help bring down Atreides, solely because afterwards Harkonnen would be a much lesser threat, if any.

Remembering that power is not wisdom, the Emperor is projected as dumb enough to hope the Great Houses in council wouldn't think Harkonnen had no place meddling with Atreides' management of Dune and if they did, wouldn't notice a few (thousand) Sardaukar boosting the Harkonnen ranks.

Comment: From my recollection of the books, there *was* good reason to throw the Harkonnen off Dune, even if the Atreides weren't a threat: spice production was well below expected. This was partly a pretense for the Emperor to replace them, but was also part of the Baron's plans: he put the brutal Rabban in charge, which decimated production and made the population desperate; Feyd could then oust Rabban, gaining the Fremen's loyalty. The Baron suspected Sardaukar were a product of their harsh Salusa Secundus environment; Dune was harsher, making the Fremen *even more* fearsome warriors.

Comment: @Warbo wasn't it that because of Rabban production plummeted AND ADDITIONALLY they "displaced" a rather large chunk of it, without anybody knowing (which was then sold on the black market for pure profit for the Harkonnens). Or am I high right now om the Water of Life?

Comment: @D.Kovács Good point! Production had to *appear* low, but that's no excuse for idle harvesters ;)

Comment: The goal of throwing the Harkonnens off Arrakis and putting the Atreides in charge was several-layered. The Harkonnens weren't performing as well as expected, so publically, placing the Atreides in charge was a measure to improve spice-production, which everyone in the universe is in favour of. It also importantly forced the Atreides to extend themselves. They could never afford to send much of their military at a time to Dune, and the Duke and his Heir would be at least temporarily far from their seat of strength and vulnerable to a decapitation strike.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 That's the Emperor trying to have his spice and eat it! Getting Atreides to boost spice production is not a step along the way to bringing down Atreides… it's a strong reason to protect Atreides.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin That's why I said "publically". The official explanation for why the Harkonnens are being kicked off Arrakis and replaced with the Atreides is that they were underperforming. The perfect excuse for getting the Atreides out of their seat-of-power and into a position where they can be destroyed, and the harkonnens are the perfect patsies to do the dirty-work since they already want to!

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 Ah… fine. So long as you acknowledge that the Harkonnens are not really being kicked off Arrakis for underperforming, but mainly as a step on the way to undermining the Atreides.

Comment: The Emperor is pretty wise in the books, he just didn't expect to be outmaneuvered by Paul Muad'Dib, an unexpected singularity of sorts. Also, not everyone in the Dune universe understands the true nature of the Spacing Guild's reliance on spice; the spice is seen as the most valuable commodity but not many realize it's *essential* for space travel and empire building!

Comment: The Emperor had a very good reason to send the Atreides to Dune and destroy them: House Atreides was starting to rival House Corrino in influence and prestige among the Great Houses, so that the Emperor -- who reached the throne by force -- was starting to suspect he could be de-throned. Also: the Atreides military was starting to rival the Sardaukar in prowess.

Comment: @AndresF What? "The Emperor is pretty wise… he just didn't expect to be outmaneuvered…" Who could justify such thinking? That "The Emperor didn't expect to be outmaneuvered…" is more than obvious.

That "The Emperor is pretty wise…" reads like nonsense. Where in the whole Dune universe is there any slight suggestion that "The Emperor is wise…"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin the evidence is that he hatched the whole plot to destroy the Atreides that is the main story of Dune. He knew he couldn't face them openly because House Atreides was popular and attacking them would turn the Landsraad against him, so he did it in an underhanded way which nearly succeeded. If it reads like nonsense, that's your problem, not mine. Maybe you would have preferred the word "cunning" intead of "wise"? Remember before being rude not all of us are native English speakers.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin by the way, when your answer is getting downvotes, it's ill advised to lash out at the commenters. Maybe consider your answer is (partly) wrong and needs fixing?

Comment: @AndresF. Pardon? If you think I was rude please explain or withdraw that.

Comment: @AndresF. Thanks and when you can show how differences - as expressed by downvotes - must be right, why not go ahead and show that?

Clearly you'd like there to be evidence that Shaddam hatched the whole plot to destroy the Atreides, and you could re-assert that ad nauseam or Post some evidence or just accept that's an opinion not borne out by real evidence.

What seems somehow obvious to you is about your perspicacity, not mine, as is shown by the simple fact that KeizerHarm Asked this Question in the first place.

IE, it isn't at all obvious Oops!

Comment: @AndresF. I certainly would not prefer the word "cunning" instead of "wise", nor anything in any way similar. That's because there is no suggestion Shaddam had any such characteristics.

In that context, he was like Hitler: having the power to enforce every slight whim says nothing about cunning or wisdom, cleverness or foresight; purely about power.